# marquee with multiple textview and focus

Tags: android, marquee

i am currently doing an android application which contains marquee with multiple textview and i want to show the contents of the textview when i click the textview .i have the code for marquee but it is not working in the case of multiple textview. i need the textview moving one after another not vertically.

plz help me.....

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mywidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:text="Simple application for marquee with example as shown" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mywidget1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:text="haihaihaihaihaihaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahiaha" 


    />



   </RelativeLayout>
```

java code

```
TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);  
    tv.setSelected(true);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mywidget1);  
    tv1.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mywidget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:lines="1"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Simple application for marquee with example as shown"
        android:textColor="#ff4500" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mywidget1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:lines="1"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="haihaihaihaihaihaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahaiahiaha"
        android:textColor="#ff4500" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this once

Comment: this code is working perfectly but i need the textview moving one after another

Comment: Then you need to concat the text and use only single textView

Comment: the two textview contains different details and i need focus for each textview.when i click the textview it must shows details of that textview

Answer (score 0):

To get it working one after another, create and start a new thread which programmatically sets the text views selected using setSelected(true) one by one with a set time interval of n microseconds between them which can be set using thread.sleep(n). Also don't forget to set all the text views initially unselected using setSelected(false).
I have not tested this personally but I am pretty sure that it will work.